# Rails 7 Jquery Not Working (Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 7 app setup (without Turbo) but with Bootstrap and Jquery.  The jquery is showing up in my sources tab under assets, but I'm still getting an error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" whenever I try to use jquery.

A sample instance where this error appears is this code, on the `$` before document:

```
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.sortable').railsSortable();
    });
  </script>
```

This error goes away if I add jquery via a CDN on my `application.html.erb` like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

....however that then starts producing all the weird errors you get when JQuery is present twice.

I have the following in my `application.js`:

```
import "controllers"
import "jquery"
import "jquery_ujs"
import "popper"
import "bootstrap"
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"

//= require jquery-ui
//= require rails_sortable
//= require activestorage
//= require font_awesome5

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

Here's my `config/importmap.rb`:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "jquery", to: "jquery.min.js", preload: true
pin "jquery_ujs", to: "jquery_ujs.js", preload: true
pin "popper", to: "popper.js", preload: true
pin "bootstrap", to: "bootstrap.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin "trix"
pin "@rails/actiontext", to: "actiontext.js"
```

And here is my `application.html.erb` head section:

```
 <head>
    ...
    <%= if content_for?(:head) then yield(:head) end %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
    <%= include_gon %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </head>
```

Can anyone see why this isn't working?  I know there's no error in the JQuery script itself (because the error is called on any $), but I can't see why the JQuery that shows in the sources tab isn't being recognized.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to use jQuery, change like this

```js
import jquery from "jquery"
window.$ = jquery
window.jQuery = jquery
```

However, if you want to use jQuery-UI, too
You need a workaround by creating a file to include the 3 lines above.

```js
// ./src/jquery.js
import jquery from "jquery"
window.$ = jquery
window.jQuery = jquery
```

And then in `application.js`

```js
import "./src/jquery"
import "jquery-ui"
```

This solution is actually from GoRails :D

https://gorails.com/episodes/how-to-use-jquery-with-esbuild

Comment: This Go Rails episode is so helpful in understanding, but I still can't get it to work.  It now shows a console error saying "The requested module 'jquery' does not provide an export named 'default'" for the `import jquery from "jquery"` line.

Comment: And now the modals don't work either.  :(

Comment: I also needed to remove the `defer: true` on the `javascript_include_tag` at the layout - it was making the $ be called before jQuery was loaded.